# Web Component: Manipulate CSS of Shadow DOM

Tags: html, css, web-component

I am using a web component that has an `iframe` tag in its root.

For example:

```html
<my-component>
  <!-- SHADOW DOM -->
  <iframe>
    ...
  </iframe>
</my-component>
```

Now when I try to style `my-component` as below, it does not seem to apply.

```css
my-component {
  cursor: default;
}
```

The default behaviour is `cursor: pointer` and I want to get rid of it. Could I access the shadow DOM via css directly, such as follows?:

```css
my-component > iframe {
  cursor: default;
}
```

Even if the `cursor: pointer` is in some deep nested HTML element, I could try and find the target this way, but I'm not sure if such a thing is even possible.

Answer (score 2):

To modify nested web components the author of the containing component must expose these, e.g. through `::part()` (read more about it here https://css-tricks.com/styling-in-the-shadow-dom-with-css-shadow-parts/#aa-styling-shadow-dom-with-part).

Otherwise, you have to use JavaScript to style nested web components.

```js
const myComponent = document.querySelector('my-component');
const childIFrame = myComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('iframe');

childIFrame.style.cursor = default;
```

If you want to reach the shadowdom of a web component nested inside another web component, you have to dig further using shadowRoot:

```js
const myComponent = document.querySelector('my-component');
const childComponent = myComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('child-component');
const childIFrame = childComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('iframe');

childIFrame.style.cursor = default;
```